# Is it true to say that all objects (besides some custom objects), has a prototype object, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it true to say that all objects (besides **some** custom objects), has a prototype object, in JavaScript?

I would bet it is indeed this way (because all out of the box objects likely to inherit properties from a prototype object besides some custom ones), but I'm not sure in that 100%.

### Edit:

I asked this after reading in first edition of JavaScript: The good parts, book about prototypes - The chapter starts:

> Every object is linked to a prototype object.

But it seemed a bit wired to me after what I read on objects in various places and I also read some definitions for prototype that were unclear to me; I wanted to see if I have a primal, basic of the concept of "prototype" in JS.

Comment: You want to know whether all, besides some, objects have a given property ? Your question is very vague...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nearly all objects in JavaScript are instances of Object; a typical object inherits properties (including methods) from Object.prototype, although these properties may be shadowed (a.k.a. overridden). However, an Object may be deliberately created for which this is not true (e.g. by Object.create(null)), or it may be altered so that this is no longer true (e.g. with Object.setPrototypeOf).

[Javascript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's false.

You can create an object without prototype:

```
var obj = Object.create(null);
```

To check whether an object has a prototype, you can do

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(someObject));
```

Comment: @NinaScholz what does that ever means ?

Comment: all build in objects have the object prototype.